# Why are my wifi Xbee not commuinicating while one connected to PC and other to the aduino board

Tags: arduino, xbee, arduino-ide

This may seem to be a questions already solved, but trust me it is not - And i am a total newbie so i don't actually understand so much of those.
I have been to all questions and tried out all answers but have not succeed.

Here is my instrument list:
1) Two XBee-s6b units, One with in-built antenna and other with external antenna
2) One Arduino Mega 2560 board
3) One USB-explorer.
4) I am using cool-term as my serial monitor and arduino IDE.
5) An XBee shield

This is how i configured my XBees (From cool-term)
XBee1 : ATID2244,ATMY1234,ATDL5678,ATWR
XBee2 : ATID2244,ATMY5678.ATDL1234,ATWR

this is my program that goes on to the board :

```
int led = 13;
int temp = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    temp = Serial.read();
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Now what i do is, I connect the board (which has the XBee on top of it connected via XBee shield) to my laptop, and select COM port whichever the board is on.
Then I'll connect the USB-Explorer with the second XBee on top of it and start cool-term, select the COM port of the second XBee.
Now if I try to write something that will make LED on board to blink, It won't do that.
Now if I select the COM port of the first XBee on Cool-Term and try to write anything on screen, It will make the LED Blink.
This implies that the xbees are not talking to each other, and I can not figure out why.
Need help, please.

P.S. The connection tutorial i am following can be found here :
http://www.norwegiancreations.com/2013/10/arduino-tutorial-1-lets-make-xbee-talk/